# Magento add custom column to Order

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9.1

I am trying to save google cookie for each single order in magento.

I would like to add new column, let's say "google_cookie" to my table. How can I achieve that ?

And which table should be updated ? Is it `sales_flat_order` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
$installer->startSetup();

$tableSales = $this->getTable('sales_flat_order');

if ($connection->tableColumnExists($tableSales, 'google_cookie') === false) {
    $connection->addColumn(
        $tableSales,
        'google_cookie',
        'varchar(255) Default Null'
    );
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

add new column using this above script and save data as per your requirement

Comment: Where do I put this script ?

Comment: put it in yourmodule/sql/yourmodule_setup folder and change version in etc/config.xml and refresh the website after cache refresh column will be added in order table thanks

Comment: Change module version in module.xml not in config!